# Getting rid of two foreach loops

Tags: php, foreach

here is my code:

```
    list($tld, $sld) = array_reverse(explode(".", $uri->getHost()));
    
    foreach ($arSiteDomains as $siteDomain) {
        list($siteTld, $siteSld) = array_reverse(explode(".", $siteDomain));

        if ($sld == $siteSld) {
            $uri->setHost($siteDomain);
            break;
        }
    }
    foreach ($arSiteDomains as $siteDomain) {
        list($siteTld, $siteSld) = array_reverse(explode(".", $siteDomain));

        if ($tld == $siteTld &&
                $sld == $siteSld
        ) {
            $uri->setHost($siteDomain);
            break;
        }
    }
```

In this code I have a current domain name in *$uri->getHost()* and a list of domains in *$arSiteDomains* array.

I'm trying to find the best matching domain and set it but I don't like two loops there. Please give me an idea to get rid of two repeating loops.

Here is an example:

```
$arSiteDomains = array(
    "en.example.com",
    "en.example.org",
    "lt.example.org",
    "lv.example.org",
);

$uri->getHost() //example.net - MUST MATCH  en.example.com
$uri->getHost() //example.org - MUST MATCH  en.example.org
$uri->getHost() //lv.example.net- MUST MATCH  lv.example.org
```

Thanks!

Comment: When asking questions about certain input / output, you should provide a few examples so we have something to work with. _"I'm trying to find the best matching domain"_ means absolutely nothing to us. We have no idea what you're doing and what you're trying to achieve. You need to provide us with _all_ the relevant details. Looking at your code, it seems you're looking for perfect matches. "Best matches" could be the closest match that's not perfect. See the confusion here?

Comment: Instead of two loops, convert one of the arrays into an associative array. Then you can look up the value directly without a loop.

Comment: Since the second loop replaces what the first loop did, you should do it first. Then only do the other loop if this loop didn't find any matches.

Comment: I provided my post with example matches I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert `$arSiteDomains` into an associative array. You can put both `$sld` and `"$siteSld.$siteTld"` in the keys of this array.

Then you can simply look up `$sld` and `"$sld.$tld"` in this array.

```
$hashSiteDomains = [];
foreach ($arSiteDomains as $siteDomain) {
    list($siteTld, $siteSld) = array_reverse(explode(".", $siteDomain));
    if (!isset($hashSiteDomains[$siteSld])) {
        $hashSiteDomains[$siteSld] = $siteDomain;
    }
    if (!isset($hashSiteDomains["$siteSld.$siteTld"])) {
        $hashSiteDomains["$siteSld.$siteTld"] = $siteDomain;
    }
}

list($tld, $sld) = array_reverse(explode(".", $uri->getHost()));
if (isset($hashSiteDomains["$sld.$tld"])) {
    $uri->setHost($hashSiteDomains["$sld.$tld"]);
} elseif (isset($hashSiteDomains["$sld"])) {
    $uri->setHost($hashSiteDomains["$sld"]);
}
```

Comment: I corrected my post once again so you can see that in your example I get an array with repeating keys.

Comment: So if there are multiple matches in `$arSiteDomains` you want the first match?

Comment: I've updated the code so only the first match for each SLD and SLD.TLD is put into the associative array.

Comment: If there are multiple matches in $arSiteDomains I want the closest match, like if there are ru.hooshop.ee, ru.hooshop.lt and ru.hooshop.lv and my doamin is www.hooshop.lt I want ru.hooshop.lt.

Comment: That's what this does. First it looks for `hooshop.it`, if that's not found it looks for `hooshop`.